# Having two viewport meta tags - will one get overwritten?

Tags: html, viewport, meta-tags

I would like to add the following property to my codebase:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="minimal-ui" />
```

However my project uses some centralised code which includes the following later down the page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Can anyone advise if the tags will clash or override each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the meta tag is handled like the title tag. If you use more than one, they get overridden by the later ones.

I do not recommend to use more than one meta viewport, the page wouldn't get validated by the W3C validator.